# How to using Jetty source code start web app

Tags: java, jetty

I have the following problem after executing the Main class directly

```bash
ERROR : No enabled jetty modules found!
INFO  : ${jetty.home} = /Users/zhangsan/git_repo/servlet-container/jetty.project
INFO  : ${jetty.base} = /Users/zhangsan/git_repo/servlet-container/jetty.project
ERROR : Please create and/or configure a ${jetty.base} directory.

Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information
```

I do not want to start with the start.jar file. What do I do

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the full JVM command line used to start jetty with the [dry-run](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-10/operations-guide/index.html#og-start-configure-dry-run) command:

```
java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --dry-run
```

This will give you all the options and classpath that is required to run Jetty with your current configuration in your jetty-base directory.

With this you can enter the configuration into your intellij run configurations options for `Main.java`. But this is not recommended, if any configuration changes in the jetty-base then the JVM command line options required will change as well.

Perhaps you should look into running with remote JVM debug as described in https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/8114, or even switching to using embedded Jetty.